# Не могу использовать базу данных в боте телеграм. Ошибка sqlite3

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу бота на aiogram.
Подключил базу данных и пытаюсь передать в нее значения из листа State.
Выдает ошибку AttributeError: **aexit**

Сначала создаю такую функцию в отдельном файле:

```
async def sql_add_command(state):
async with state.proxy as data:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (?,?,?,?,)', tuple(data_values()))
    base.commit()
```

Потом обращаюсь к ней после завершения конечных автоматов:

```
...
await state.update_data(name_user=message.text.title())
global user_data
user_data = await state.get_data()
**await sql_db.sql_add_command(state)**
await state.finish()
```

Traceback выдает AttributeError: **aexit** на строчку, выделенную **.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не поставил скобочки у state.proxy()